# how to replicate scipy.stats.fit using optimization function?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am trying to fit a distribution to some values.  This is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    values = np.random.pareto(1.5, 10000)
    loc = values.min()
    scale = 1


    def cost_function(alpha):
        cost = -sp.stats.pareto(alpha, loc=loc, scale=scale).pdf(values)
        return cost.sum()

    opt_res = opt.fmin(cost_function, 1.5)

    alpha_fit_v = sp.stats.pareto.fit(values, floc=loc, fscale=scale)


    print('opt_res = ', opt_res,
          ' alpha_fit_v = ', alpha_fit_v)
```

I was expecting `alpha_fit_v` to be equivalent to `opt_res` but it is not. What's wrong?.

Comment: Could you include you import statements as well!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's wrong?.

1. The cost function is wrong.
2. `np.random.pareto` has a different distribution than `sp.stats.pareto`

#### 1. The cost function is wrong

It does not make sense to sum inverse probabilities. You need to use the logarithm:

```
def cost_function(alpha):
    cost = -sp.stats.pareto(alpha, loc=loc, scale=scale).logpdf(values)
    return cost.sum()
```

#### 2. `np.random.pareto` has a different distribution than `sp.stats.pareto`

This one is tricky, but you may have noticed that not even `sp.stats.pareto.fit` returns the correct result. This is because scipy's Pareto distribution cannot fit the data generated by numpy.

```
import matplpotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipys as sp
import numpy as np

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.hist(np.random.pareto(1.5, 10000), 1000)  # This is a Lomax or Pareto II distribution
plt.xlim(0, 10)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.hist(sp.stats.pareto.rvs(1.5, size=1000), 1000)  # This is a Pareto distribution
plt.xlim(0, 10)
```

[image: distributions]

That said, this will work as expected:

```
values = sp.stats.pareto.rvs(1.5, size=1000)
loc = 0
scale = 1

def cost_function(alpha):
    cost = -sp.stats.pareto(alpha, loc=loc, scale=scale).logpdf(values)
    return cost.sum()

opt_res = opt.fmin(cost_function, 1.5)

alpha_fit_v = sp.stats.pareto.fit(values, floc=loc, fscale=scale)

print('opt_res = ', opt_res,
      ' alpha_fit_v = ', alpha_fit_v)

# opt_res =  [ 1.49611816]  alpha_fit_v =  (1.4960937500000013, 0, 1)
```

According to the documentation [`numpy.random.pareto`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.pareto.html) does not quite draw from *the* Pareto distribution:

> Draw samples from a **Pareto II or Lomax distribution** with specified shape.
>
> The Lomax or Pareto II distribution is a **shifted Pareto distribution**. The classical Pareto distribution can be obtained from the Lomax distribution by **adding 1** and multiplying by the scale parameter m (see Notes).

So you have two alternatives if using numpy to generate the data:

- You can set `loc=-1` for the scipy distribution.
- You can do `values = np.random.pareto(1.5, 10000) + 1` and set `loc=0`.

Comment: what is the difference between the two pareto? numpy vs scipy

Comment: I've included these beautiful histograms and you still ask? :( Well, the numpy distribution is shiftet by 1. numpy-pareto values start at 0, whereas scipy-pareto values start at 1. The `loc` parameter can compensate for this (`loc=-1` is equivalent to the numpy distribution)

Comment: so from the pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution  `xm` is 0 for numpy and -1 for scipy?

Comment: @Donbeo I think `xm` is 1 for both distributions (this is the scale parameter), but scipy does have a locatoin parameter `loc` that can be used to shift the distribution on the x axis. Looking at the plots on the Wikipedia page it seems that the distribution *should* start at 1. Perhaps the numpy implementation is wrong?

Comment: Ah, it's not wrong. numpy: "Draw samples from a Pareto II or Lomax distribution...  a shifted Pareto distribution". I'll edit this into the answer.